# Practical determination of anomaly threshold in (variational) autoencoders

Tags: python, tensorflow, threshold, autoencoder

Although not strictly a programming question, I haven't found anything about this topic on this site. I currently dealing with (variational) autoencoders ((V)AE), and plan to deploy them to detect anomalies. For testing purposes, I've implemented an VAE in tensorflow for detecting handwritten digits.

The training went well and the reconstructed images are very similar to the originals. But for actually using the autoencoder, I have to use some kind of measure to determine if a new image fed to the autoencoder is a digit or not by comparing it to a threshold value.

At this point, I have two major questions:

1.) For training, I used a loss consisting of two components. First one is the reconstruction error, which is a crossentropy function:

```
# x: actual input
# x_hat: reconstructed input
epsilon = 1e-10  # <-- small number for numeric stability within log
recons_loss = - f.reduce_sum( x * tf.log( epsilon + x_hat) + (1 - x) * tf.log( epsilon + 1 - x_hat),
                             axis=1)
```

The second one is KL-divergence, which is a measure of how similar two probability distributions are, as we are demanding that the latent variable space is a distribution similar to a Gaussian.

```
# z_mean: vector representing the means of the latent distribution
# z_log_var: vector representing the variances of the latent distribution
KL_div = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum( 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var),
                              axis=1)
```

**For determining the reconstruction error of a new image, do I have to use both parts of the training loss?** Intuitively, I would say no and just go with the recon_loss.

2.) **How do I determine the threshold value? Is there already a tf functionality implemented that I can use?**

If you have some good source for anything related, please share the link!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. VAEs are very well in projecting a high dimensional data into a lower dimensional latent space. Altering the latent vector and feeding it to the decoder part creates new samples.

I hope I get your question right, you try to do an anomaly detection with the encoder part on the lower dimensional latent space?

I guess you have trained your VAE on MNIST. What you can do is getting all latent vectors of the MNIST-digits and compare the latent vector of your new digit via euclidian distance to them. The threshold would be a max distance set by you.

The code would be something like this:

```
x_mnist_encoded = encoder.predict(x_mnist, batch_size=batch_size) #array of MNIST latent vectors
test_digit_encoded = encoder.predict(x_testdigit, batch_size=1) #your testdigit latent vector

#calc the distance
from scipy.spatial import distance
threshold = 0.3 #min eucledian distance

for vector in x_mnist_encoded:
 dst = distance.euclidean(vector,test_digit_encoded[0])

 if dst <= threshold:
  return True
```

VAE code is from https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Comment: To make things clear: I have trained my VAE on MNIST, now I want to test if it can detect if a non-digit image is fed to it, e. g. an 'X'. This should be indicated somehow. I thought that I use both parts, encoder and decoder, and somehow compare the raw image to my reconstructed image. I don't know if the Euclidean distance could be suitable for this.

Comment: What you describe is a simple binary classification problem. If you really want to use an VAE model for it as some kind of unsupervised model. You would use just the latent vector representation from the encoder part.

Comment: The decoder is just cool to generate new digits. Another way to do your classification is to fit a oneclassSVM on the MNIST-latent vectors.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But isn't it computationally expensive to compare a new image to all MNIST digits in the latent space? Also, assume my latent space is 2-dimensional, how would the formula look like? To me it seems strange to sum up the squared differences of means and variances, as it is like adding apples to bananas.

Comment: Also, I have found an interesting paper [here](http://dm.snu.ac.kr/static/docs/TR/SNUDM-TR-2015-03.pdf). It does not use the latent representation of the model, it rather reconstructs its inputs and uses a custom reconstruction probability to evaluate if the input is anomalous or not. This is contradicting to what you proposed. Can you clarify this please? @Daniel Tremer

Comment: The paper seems interesting, I need to read it more carefully. Conserning your problem, even in a 2d latent space you cpuld calculate the distance between the points and your new digit. And yes it is computational intensive, to compare your point to all mnist points but would be O(n). Using the latent representation was my first guess since in theory what it does is a dimensional reduction which can be used for further classification.